# MobaXterm - remember the server name

Tags: ssh, server, settings, mobaxterm

How can I "tell" MobaXterm to remember the server names I was previously connected to, the next time I use it?

I know we have the option of creating a new session (user session) and this way it will remain saved, however, I don't want to create sessions for all the servers I am connecting to. I would want MobaXterm to remember the next time I am ssh-ing on a previous used server.

Many thanks.